# Scalac can't compile a function parametrized over TraversableOnce[_] and the element type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a use case for a function that is parametrized over any type that is a `TraversableOnce[T]` for any `T`. I tried to use

```
def test[T, F[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](ts: F[T]): Unit = {
  ts.foldLeft("")((acc: String, t: T) => if (acc.isEmpty) t.toString else acc + "," + t.toString)
}
```

but Scalac complains in a way that I've found strange:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, T) => String
 required: (String, _$1) => String
           ts.foldLeft("")((acc: String, t: T) => if (acc.isEmpty) t.toString else acc + "," + t.toString)
```

Now I know that I can use the constraint `F[T] <: TraversableOnce[T]` but I would like to understand why Scalac can't work with the version of the function that I've just written. The type of `ts` is `F[T]` and thus the type of the second argument of `foldLeft` should be `(String, T) => String` and not `(String, _$1) => String` with `_$1` is unknown. What is happening here?

Comment: som-snytt should get the credit for the right answer on this one. I initially misread the question, and then went back and edited my answer to actually respond to your question. But som-snytt answered correctly before I corrected myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't tied your type parameter to the type parameter of the traversable.

You're passing a function that requires a `T`, but the unknown type parameter of the traversable is not constrained.

```
scala> def f[T, F[T] <: TraversableOnce[T]](ts: F[T]) = ts.foldLeft("") _
f: [T, F[T] <: TraversableOnce[T]](ts: F[T])((String, T) => String) => String

scala> def f[T, F[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](ts: F[T]) = ts.foldLeft("") _
f: [T, F[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](ts: F[T])((String, Any) => String) => String
```

The notation `TO[_]` is shorthand for `TO[t] forSome { type t }`, where `_$1` is the `t` for your traversable.

Comment: Suppose you have a `F[X with Z]`, `F[X] <: TO[Y]` b/c `X <:< Y`, but `ts` is `F[Z]`. We haven't said anything about the type relation of `Z` and `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

A signature like this:

```
def test[T, F[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](ts: F[T]): Unit
```

is not the same as a signature like this:

```
def test[T, F[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](ts: F[T]): Unit
```

In the latter case, you are saying that F "F is a type with a single type parameter that is a subclass of TraversableOnce, whenever the F and the TraversableOnce have the same type parameter." The version with the underscores means something more like "F is a type with a single parameter that is a subclass of TraversableOnce[Any]".

The reason for the difference in meaning is that the two underscores in the first version are unrelated. In that signature, `TraversableOnce[_]` is the same as `TraversableOnce[Any]`, while in `F[_]`, the underscore acts as a free variable. It's equivalent to saying this:

```
def test[T, F[X] <: TraversableOnce[_]](ts: F[T]): Unit
```

Here, the `X` is a free variable that is not bound to anything outside of `F[X]`.

Comment: I've never seen a situation where the Scala compiler sees two different usages as `_` and decides that you mean them to be the same thing.